# Client side onthefly video generation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, video, client-side-scripting

At this moment i'm using php to convert a stats logs (arround 40k rows) to png graphics (bars, animations) and then using ffmpeg to convert the sequential images (20fps) to video,

a single request of this animation last arround 10 mins on a 2x3.06ghz intel core dedicated server and cost arround 2gb of disk space for png files and 500Mb for the video file

My first trouble is with my hdd space, just 10 users can ruin my 40Gb hdd in few hours...

So i wonder a way to grab each png frame on local storage (maybe generating first the image on a canvas) and then merge all frames togheter (motionjpg?)

I found this javascript plugin but even works for me http://ushiroad.com/mjpeg/

Comment: Do you need it as an actual video? Seems like you could do this with a charting library or canvas.

Comment: You may consider using a YouTube / Vimeo (or similar) API to offset the server storage and display the videos directly from those services.

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz. If you're doing some sort of log animation, then render it with a charting library using JSON data you grab from your server every minute or so. With the data you give, that's 4K rows per minute, which is fine for an AJAX operation (though you can tune this up or down for bandwidth and responsiveness).

Comment: necessarily need it in a video format ready for download, the point of this is to put this video overlayed into another video (telemetry overlay over race onboard camera) so people need it downloaded to their computers to deal with it on their video editing software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this with [ming](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php)! I'm generating animations from 60Kb row `json` in just  0.7secs with a final `swf` video of 300Kb

A `swf` file can then be imported by practically every editing video software out there.